# Php Search Form in post method doesn't return data

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

i'm building a search fonctionality using php in Laravel 5.6, at first i created a form in get method and it was working well but i need it to be in post method and my problem is that no data are returning at all. I'm a bit lost now cause i don't understand why it is not working, can someone help me to understand where my mistakes are? Thanks (and sorry if my english doesn't sound good, i'm a frenchie !)

This my controller

```
<?php

 namespace App\Http\Controllers;

 use App\Telephone;
 use  Illuminate\Http\Request;


 class TelephoneController extends Controller{

 public function index(Request $request){
    $nom = $request->input('nom');
    $site = $request->input('site');
    $groupe = $request->input('groupe');

    $listSite = Telephone::query()
        ->selectRaw('Site')
        ->groupBy('Site')
        ->get();

    $listGroup = Telephone::query()
        ->selectRaw('Groupe')
        ->groupBy('Groupe')
        ->get();

    if (empty($_POST['submit'])) {
        $query = Telephone::query()
            ->select('*')
            ->orderBy('Site')
            ->orderBy('Groupe')
            ->get();
    } else {
        $query = Telephone::query()
            ->where('Nom', 'LIKE', '%' . $nom . '%')
            ->orWhere('Site', 'LIKE', '%' . $site . '%')
            ->orwhere('Groupe', 'LIKE', '%' . $groupe . '%')
            ->orderBy('Site')
            ->orderBy('Groupe')
            ->get();
    }
    return view('telephone.index', ['query' => $query, 'listSite' => $listSite, 'listGroup' => $listGroup, 'nom' => $nom, 'site' => $site, 'groupe' => $groupe]);
}

public function store(Request $request)
{
    $nom = $request->nom;
    $site = $request->site;
    $groupe = $request->groupe;

    return redirect('telephone')->with($nom, $site, $groupe);
}
}
```

And this is my view

```
<h2 class="text-center titre">Répertoire d'entreprise </h2>
{{ Form::open(['method'=>'POST','class'=>'col-lg-12','role'=>'recherche']) }}
{{ csrf_field() }}

<div class="row formulaire">
   <div class="form-group col-lg-6 ">
            {!! Form::label('nom', 'Recherche par nom : ') !!}
            <input type="text" name="nom" class="form-control" id="nom" value="{{$nom}}"
                   placeholder="Recherche ...">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-lg-2">
            {!! Form::label('site', 'Site ') !!}
            <select class="form-control" id="selectSite" name="site" value="{{$site}}">
                <option selected disabled>site</option>
                @foreach($listSite as $site)
                    <option>{{$site->Site}}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-lg-2">
            {!! Form::label('groupe', 'Groupe ') !!}
            <select class="form-control" id="selectGroupe" name="groupe" value="{{$groupe}}">
                <option selected disabled>...</option>
                @foreach($listGroup as $list)
                    <option value="{{$list->Groupe}}">{{$list->Groupe}}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group col-lg-2">
            {{ Form::submit('Recherche', ['class'=>'btn btn-light','type'=>'submit','name'=>'submit'])}}
        </div>
        {!! Form::close() !!}
   </div>
<div class="responsive-table-line">
    <table class="table table-hover table-sm table-condensed table-body-center">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Nom</th>
            <th scope="col">Poste</th>
            <th scope="col">N°interne</th>
            <th scope="col">N°externe</th>
            <th scope="col">Portable</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php $site = ""; $groupe = "";?>
        @foreach(   $query as $row)
            @if($row->Site != $site)
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="5" class="table-secondary"><h3 class="site">{{$row->Site}}</h3></td>
                </tr>
            @endif
            @if($row->Groupe != $groupe && $row->Groupe != "")
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="5" class="table-active "><p class="groupe">{{$row->Groupe}}</p></td>
                </tr>
            @endif
            <tr>
                <td id="nom">{{$row->Nom}}</td>
                <td>{{$row->Fonction}}</td>
                <td>{{$row->Poste_interne}}</td>
                <td>{{$row->Poste_externe}}</td>
                <td>{{$row->Portable}}</td>
            </tr>
            <?php $site = $row->Site; $groupe = $row->Groupe?>
        @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

web.php is simple

```
Route::resource('/telephone', 'TelephoneController' );
```

Someone can explain my mistakes please? why it isn't return the response into my table? Thanks

Comment: You have two forms in your VIEW remove second FORM tag ```<form class="form-control ">``` and its closing tag.

Comment: thank you very much ! i didn't notice that it could be a problem, but still not working

Comment: Post your update code after removing extra ```<form>``` tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In TelephoneController@store,

can you

`return [$nom, $site, $groupe];`

and see the data there before passing it to your view?

Then try,

`return view('telephone', compact('nom', 'site', 'groupe');`

And in your view, just echo out the variables {{ $nom }} and you should be able to see them

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for your help! the first return seems to work well, it return my research and the second one return an error "Undefined variable: listSite" ...

Comment: your variable names need to be the same. If you pass 'site' your .blade file expects to see a $site variable

Comment: yes i guess but i can't figure it out how to code this cause if i replace $row->Nom by $nom, the foreach doesn't find anything! very frustating !

Comment: Before you start the foreach, make sure you can echo out the data. Then you can try @ foreach ($row as $index => $nom) { {{ $index, $nom }} @ endforeach. PS, once you get this make sure to learn Vue.js :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot Dazzle, i will edit the post when it will be working! thanks for the advice i'd love to learn vue.js when i will be more confident with php :)

Comment: No prob, don't forget to upvote and mark correct answer !

Comment: Keep going, you will get there. Great free vue2 series on laracasts